# Could not open JPG file in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpg

I download Image from an Internet and want to open this jpeg Image in Photoshop but I got an error
[image]
`Could not complete your request because of a problem parsing the JPEG Data.`

Comment: Will it open in any other application (eg. web browser, Windows image viewer...)? Perhaps the file got corrupted.

Comment: I can open it in window photo viewer.

Comment: Hard to say, then. Maybe you could try to use the `print screen` button to copy and paste a shot of it in Photoshop, if that's sufficinet for your purposes?

Comment: Try re-downloading the JPG. Maybe it didn't download completely.

Comment: You could also try opening the file in a program that likes it and then re-saving, as per [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/parsing-the-jpeg-data-i-cant-get-photos-to-go-into/9d48ab97-f0fa-4cfd-ad50-2f951d552b37), or you could try wiping the metadata from `Properties->Details->Remove Properties and Personal Information`.

Comment: It is possible that it is not actually a JPEG and Photoshop's programmers have chosen to not make PS open the file by testing for an alternate file type. JPEG files have a text tag int he first few bytes "JFIF". If it is not too large, you can open it with a text editor (or hex editor) and look for this tag.

Comment: this exact issue happened to me yesterday. i was trying to open an 80MB jpg. what's the size of your image? my work around was to open it in fireworks and resave it slightly compressed. but i'll be watching this question for a better solution.

Comment: Before you get into a messy complicated thing: 1. rename file and make sure it has extention .jpg 2. _download it again_

Comment: With Instagram, you can get the link to an image from the source code. Ctrl+U, F12, right click 'inspect...' etc and get the image link. It is currently hidden one element above the selection in the code. Then open that image in a new tab, Save as... and add the extension (choose "all file types" and add .jpg). If for some reason this does not work: right click and copy the image while it is open in a new tab in your browser. Go to PS File>New (Ctrl + N etc.). By default the new canvas will be the right size as the image in clipboard. Paste and save as JPEG ;)

Comment: What worked for me was to open the image in a web browser (I used Chrome), then right click and choose Copy Image. Then paste into Photoshop.

Comment: Did you download the image from Instagram?

Answer (score 3):

when you look at the file in your windows (or mac) explorer, can you see an associated icon with the file? If it appears as a blank page there might be a possibility that the image extension was not appended to the end of the file name. I have had this difficulty with programs in the past.

[image]

If it is a "blank" page like the above icon (2014_C) you can try and rename the file and add ".jpg" at the end of the file. This won't necessarily fix it 100%...you may still have a bad download, but at least this is one way to try and make sure the file is associated with a program.

Non-associated files will open in some programs, but not always. Just a suggestion to look for.

Comment: How can I send you the Images. I am facing problem with so that you can see and solve this. These Images are not getting open in Photoshop,

Comment: you can add them to a drop box and send the link

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem.

1. Close Photoshop
2. Refresh the screen
3. Open the folder where the file is
4. Point the file, right click and - Open with - Photoshop

It's open. Done.